# Having trouble extending magento's account template/view

Tags: magento

How do I go about modifying the ~/customer/account/index template/layout/view without overwriting the original from Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the template, create your own theme and copy it into that theme. To modify the layout, use `local.xml`. By view, I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean Block, you'll need to learn to override blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto Joseph's Answer, there's more details on how to override the blocks here:

http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/